# Laravel error upon submitting a form: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218. What could this be due to?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

There is a form in my view, from where, on clicking submit, data is taken to ajax script which is supposed to invoke the controllers specified in the post routes in routes.php. The controllers are expected to process the received data and throw the result back to the view. Why is this error occurring immediately after submitting the form and things aren't working as expected>

Comment: You're probably sending the data as `GET` when it should be `POST`. Show us how you make the AJAX call and the route definition it should be hitting.

Comment: here it is : https://pastebin.com/WdVLfFa4

Comment: Well, you're posting to `post/store`, but you have no `post/store` route.

Comment: made the necessary changes, yet the error persists. https://pastebin.com/F52Hn8zQ

Answer (score 1):

Check your routes.php file. Make sure that the method your using corresponds with what you have allowed.

[Here is the laravel documenation for routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

For example, if your request is a GET request, the call should look like this in the routes file:

```
Route::get('/test-get-url', function ()    {
    // Matches The "/test-get-url" URL using a GET method
});
```

And for post

```
Route::post('/test-post-url', function ()    {
    // Matches The "/test-post-url" URL using a POST method
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal/cmd..whichever you using and type

```
php artisan route:list
```

this will list all your routes and check at what route your is being submitted.Note the corresponding method to be used in the Method column and use that method while submitting form.I'm assuming it's `PUT` method(which is most likely).Ex--

Use `method` attribute if you're using simple HTML code like--

```
<form action="{{route='..'}}" method="PUT">
```

or if you're using form helper then use--

```
{!! Form::open($post, ['route' => ['..'], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your route.php file and check

Route::get('someroute',['uses'=>'somecontroller@function_get','as'=>'some_get']);
    Route::post('someroute',['uses'=>'somecontroller@funtion_post','as'=>'some_post']);

make sure if your are using (as) in you routes its different and also where you use your ajax you properly define your route where you want to post your form data and it's type is same as you mention in routes and one more thing check you properly use (;) in your code

hope this will help you fell free to ask your query

Comment: could you send your route file in comment  , i think there might be some prefix group that might be left or say forgot to put in ajax url

Comment: Here : https://pastebin.com/bGFURgAt . Though it's more or less the same